# ahk script hotkeys losing their original functions

Tags: autohotkey

I use some hotkeys in an ahk script but they don't do their original functions if I assign hotkeys. Example: I may have double press esc for alt + f4 closing an application but then esc does not do its normal esc functionality with just one click. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just learned tilde ~ solves this issue when put in front of the hotkey. Example: instead of Esc::, write ~Esc::